# BERT vs distilBERT: reduce the number of layers

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, distilbert

I am exploring BERT model and its distiled version - distilBERT. I am reading to part 3 of  [DistilBERT, a distilled version of BERT: smaller, faster, cheaper and lighter paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.01108.pdf) and know that the number of layer of distiBERT is reduced by factor of 2.

I don't know why reduced by the factor of 2. Can reduce the number of layers by the another number?